# How to merge date and time from two separate columns into a new datetime column using csvHelper in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, csvhelper

I have the following CSV file with the following format.
[image]

Using csvHelper in the following code snippet (using Visual Studio 2019), I can successfully read the file.

```
public ActionResult UploadCsvFile(IFormFile file)
        {
            if (file != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    var basePath = Path.Combine(_hostEnvironment.WebRootPath, "uploads/");
                    if (!Directory.Exists(basePath))
                        Directory.CreateDirectory(basePath);    
                    var filePath = Path.Combine(basePath, file.FileName);
                    using (var stream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                    {
                        file.CopyTo(stream);
                    }   
                    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
                    {
                        Delimiter = ";",
                        HasHeaderRecord = true
                    };
                    using (var Reader = new StreamReader(filePath))  
                    using (var csv = new CsvReader(Reader, config))
                    {
                        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<CsvLineClassMap>();
                        var records = csv.GetRecords<CsvLine>().ToList();   
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e);
                }
            }
            return Json(null);
        }
```

From the debugging window I can see the data records (From there you can see the separate columns of date and time).
[image]

But, I need to get as a result in a single column with datetime format, As the following recreated.
[image]

I have investigated, but have not been able to solve it.
:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Convert` method in the `ClassMap`

```cs
void Main()
{
    System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("es");

    var data = new StringBuilder();
    data.AppendLine("Code;Date;Time;Level;Flow;Volumen");
    data.AppendLine("OB-0100-99;16.07.2021;19:00:00;125,53;38,8;1621770");
    data.AppendLine(";16.07.2021;20:00:00;138,6;69,4;1621780");

    var config = new CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
    {
        Delimiter = ";"
    };
    
    using (var streamReader = new StringReader(data.ToString()))
    using (var csv = new CsvReader(streamReader, config))
    {
        csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<CsvLineClassMap>();
        var records = csv.GetRecords<CsvLine>().ToList().Dump();
    }
    
}

public class CsvLineClassMap : ClassMap<CsvLine>
{
    public CsvLineClassMap()
    {
        Map(x => x.Flow);
        Map(x => x.Code);
        Map(x => x.DateTime).Convert(x => 
        { 
            return DateTime.ParseExact(
                x.Row.GetField("Date") + " " + x.Row.GetField("Time"),
                "dd.MM.yyyy H:mm:ss",
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        });
        Map(x => x.Level);
        Map(x => x.Volumen);
    }
}

public class CsvLine
{
    public double Flow { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }
    public double Level { get; set; }
    public double Volumen { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Test your code in LINQPad6 and it works perfect. Then using VS2019 update my method in the ClassMap as you suggest, but when reading my CSV file it throws the following exception:
System.FormatException: String '16 .07.2021 0:00:00 'was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Using .NET5 in VS2019 update my method in the ClassMap as you suggest, but when reading my CSV file it throws the following exception: System.FormatException: String '16 .07.2021 0:00:00 'was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Looks like the issue is with the time format. HH is "The hour, using a 24-hour clock from 00 to 23". H is "The hour, using a 24-hour clock from 0 to 23". HH doesn't like the "0:00:00" time.  I changed the string time format to "dd.MM.yyyy H:mm:ss".

Comment: Thank you very very much. Now it works 100%. Thanks for all the help and explanation. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are casting the result to a POCO, then write a getter method, in which you concat the Date and Time field and cast it and return it as a DateTime property.

(or)

Use this function

```
DateTime GetDateTime(string date, string time)
{
    return DateTime.ParseExact(date + " " + time, "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
}
```

and append the result to the return list.

Answer (score 0):

Try add an item to your list `records` and concatenate Date field and Time field as follow:

```
...
using (var csv = new CsvReader(Reader, config))
{
    csv.Context.RegisterClassMap<CsvLineClassMap>();
    var records = csv.GetRecords<CsvLine>().ToList();

    var newDateTime = new DateTime();
    newDateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(records[2] + " " + records[2]);
    records.Add(newDateTime);
}
...
```

also, you can use the following for the date convert part and format date and time:

```
DateTime dt1 = DateTime.ParseExact(records[2] + " " + records[2], "dd/MM/yy h:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: I don't need to add another column to my record list.                                                           When I read the CSV file, I need it to show only one column with datetime, I don't want two separate columns with date & time.

Comment: I don't want to use a new method to get the date and time together and then concatenate it.
I would like to do it directly while using the Csvhelper library.